# U.S. to U.K. visa application

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, us-residents

I am an Indian national individual currently in U.S. with a work visa. I want to visit U.K. and Netherlands while going back to India. Is it possible to get Visa for the U.K. and Netherlands while residing in the U.S. for an Indian National?

Comment: You cannot get a single visa for the UK and the Netherlands, but as @MichaelHampton (to whom thanks) has pointed out, this is commonplace. Close voting as unclear because it's hard to know if you are referring to a single visa, or have some other issue about the application process.

Comment: I cannot get single VISA for these two countries but I can get separate ones right?

Comment: Of course you can get separate visas. Is that your question? Are you asking if having a US visa obviates the possibility of getting UK/Schengen visas?  Close vote remains.

Comment: @GayotFow No I am concerned if being an Indian, is it possible to apply U.K. Visa from U.S.? I will be in U.S. with work visa. I am sorry I have no idea about how to close votes

Comment: @AkshayGupta I have edited your question to make it clearer. If that does not reflect what you are actually asking feel free to undo my edit.

Comment: @AkshayGupta you have an answer posted now; see if it fits your needs and if so, accept it.  Otherwise consider clarifying your question again, thanks

Comment: On the topic of your visa for the Netherlands, you are actually required to apply for it in your place or residence. You cannot apply for it in India. Because you reside in the US, you must apply for it in the US. There is no need to write *visa* in all caps.

Comment: @phoog But I will be on a project in U.S. for 5 months. I am not a resident of U.S. Even then I can apply from US right?

Comment: @AkshayGupta it depends on your specific travel plans. If you'll be in your country of residence during the three months before your trip then the consulate in the US will probably not accept your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should have no trouble applying for a UK visa from the US. I have done this a number of times and I am in the same situation as you are - foreign national in the USA on a work visa.

You'll have to complete the online application forms on the [UK Visas & Immigration web site](https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/uk-visas-and-immigration) and then send your passport to the UK consulate nearest to you. You will probably also have to visit a location where your biometric information will be recorded (fingerprints, photo, etc) and there are many of these offices in major cities across the USA.
Assuming your application is successful you'll receive it back in a few weeks with a visa.

I imagine the process for the Netherlands is pretty much the same, but not something I have personal experience with.

Remember that you'll have to allow for processing time for both visas - probably at least 2 months (maybe more) as you'll be sending your passport off for one visa, waiting for it to return, then sending it off for the other one.
I would avoid making any firm travel plans until the visa processes are all complete.

Comment: @AkshayGupta also keep in mind that you cannot apply for the Schengen visa (Netherlands) more than 3 months before your intended trip.